# How do I handle snapped in winrt with a 728 sized ad?

Tags: windows-runtime, ads

Wondering If anyone has an experience with this. You have the large 728x90 ad in your metro app and the user snaps your app to the side obviously 728 is no longer an option...

Do I have to change my ad unit? and ad control size? seems like there must be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ad size using CSS code (you can change all numbers in your way):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #your_ad_id {width:000px;height:000px;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    #your_ad_id {width:000px;height:000px;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    #your_ad_id {width:000px;height:000px;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 959px) {
    #your_ad_id {width:000px;height:000px;}
}
```

Comment: My fault for not specifying that I am using xaml. That is good advice for an html based app though. I ended up just creating two ad controls at the appropriate sizes depending on snapped or full. I'll mark this as the answer since I didnt specify and it will help for html apps.